# flutter wrap content on two rows only and scroll the rest

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to wrap the content on two rows only, and hide and scroll hrizontally the rest of items.like this image.

```
 final list = [
    "Zumba" , "Yoga" , "Body Buildeing", "Abs" , "Total Weight" ,
    "Bodyweight Exercise" , "Total body fit"
  ];






Container(
    height: 100,
    child: Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
      runSpacing: 5.0,
      spacing: 5.0,
      children: list.map((item) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          color: Colors.grey,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
            child: Text(item,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList()
    ),
  ),
```

[Like this iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJKGl.png)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RBVyam17Z0_dDrpMOpSO5ZLtj_dPkndf/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Column with 2 Rows, inside a Listview with scrolldirection horizontal.

Here's the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: getCards(),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: getCards(),
                )
              ],
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getCards() {
    final list = [
      "Zumba",
      "Yoga",
      "Body Buildeing",
      "Abs",
      "Total Weight",
      "Bodyweight Exercise",
      "Total body fit"
    ];
    return list.map((item) {
      return Card(
        elevation: 5,
        color: Colors.grey,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
          child: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

UPDATE:

I changed the code so that your list would be divided in 2 rows, half in the first and the other half in the second.

I added a crossAxisAlignement to the column for the rows to be aligned on the left.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: getCards(),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getCards() {
    final list = [
      "Zumba",
      "Yoga",
      "Body Buildeing",
      "Abs",
      "Total Weight",
      "Bodyweight Exercise",
      "Total body fit"
    ];
    List<Widget> res = [];
    res.add(Row(
        children: list.sublist(0, list.length ~/ 2 + 1).map((item) {
      return Card(
        elevation: 5,
        color: Colors.grey,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
          child: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList()));
    res.add(Row(
        children: list.sublist(list.length ~/ 2 + 1).map((item) {
      return Card(
        elevation: 5,
        color: Colors.grey,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
          child: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList()));
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: this show the same content twice, I did not want to show item more than one time

Comment: I know, but I did't handle that logic becouse that wasn't your question.
How do you want them to be devided? I'm gonna update the code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @l-gangemi 
I want the half of my list to show in the first listview and the rest to show in the other listview. ex:  show ( "Zumba" , "Yoga" , "Body Buildeing", "Abs" ) in the first list
and show the other items in the second list.

Comment: Please consider accepting or at least upvoting the answer if it helped

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot @l-gangemi